# is unknown to this NavController inside tab layout

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm implementing a navigation component but I have a problem when my fragment is inside tab layout it is showing an error like this:

> /action_previousMatchFragment_to_detailMatchFragment is unknown to this NavController

```java
class MatchAdapter(private val listMatchItems: List<Match.MatchItem>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MatchAdapter.MatchViewHolder>() {

    private var itemClickListener:((Match.MatchItem) -> Unit)? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MatchViewHolder {
        return MatchViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_match, parent, false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = listMatchItems.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MatchViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val matchItem: Match.MatchItem = listMatchItems[position]
        holder.bindItem(matchItem)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            itemClickListener?.invoke(matchItem)
        }
    }


    fun setItemClickListener(listener: (matchItem: Match.MatchItem) -> Unit) {
        itemClickListener = listener
    }

}


class PreviousMatchFragment : Fragment(), PreviousMatchImpl.View {

    private var matchItems: MutableList<Match.MatchItem> = mutableListOf()
    private val adapter by lazy {
        MatchAdapter(
            matchItems
        )
    }
    private lateinit var presenter: PreviousMatchPresenter

    private var leagueId: String? = null

    fun newInstance(leagueId: String): PreviousMatchFragment {
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("leagueId", leagueId)

        val fragment = PreviousMatchFragment()
        fragment.arguments = bundle

        return fragment
    }

    private fun readBundle(bundle: Bundle?) {
        if (bundle != null) {
            leagueId = bundle.getString("leagueId")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_last_match, container, false)

        arguments?.let { readBundle(it) }

        adapter.setItemClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(PreviousMatchFragmentDirections.actionPreviousMatchFragmentToDetailMatchFragment(leagueId))
        }
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        presenter = PreviousMatchPresenter(this)
        leagueId?.let { presenter.getListMatch(it) }
        rv_last_match.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        rv_last_match.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun setDataList(data: List<Match.MatchItem>) {
        matchItems.clear()
        matchItems.addAll(data)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

The full error is:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.example.rifqi.footballapp:id/action_previousMatchFragment_to_detailMatchFragment is unknown to this NavController

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `R.layout.fragment_last_match` as fragment where NavController should be. That is not how you use NavController.

Your             `Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(PreviousMatchFragmentDirections.actionPreviousMatchFragmentToDetailMatchFragment(leagueId))`

should be

`Navigation.findNavController(R.ID.OF_NAV_HOST_FRAGMENT).navigate(PreviousMatchFragmentDirections.actionPreviousMatchFragmentToDetailMatchFragment(leagueId))`

where R.ID.OF_NAV_HOST_FRAGMENT is id of NavHostFragment, not just any fragment.